# Is it illegal to drive a car by oneself as a foreigner in Myanmar?

Tags: international, driving, myanmar

Is it illegal to drive a car by oneself as a foreigner (French citizen and US permanent resident) in Myanmar?

I have read some for conflicting information, e.g.

- https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/topics/rent-a-car-with-no-driver ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191014065125/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/topics/rent-a-car-with-no-driver)): illegal
- https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294190-i9408-k12302225-Self_Drive_in_Myanmar_as_of_2018_early_2019-Myanmar.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191014064926/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294190-i9408-k12302225-Self_Drive_in_Myanmar_as_of_2018_early_2019-Myanmar.html)): legal

But none of these webpages refer to any official text anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a straightforward official answer. The [Road Transportation Administration Department](http://www.myanmarrtad.com/?q=en/article/79) states the rules for licenses, which include the following:

> (l)      Required  documents  to  apply  International  Driving 
>   Permit (IDP)                                                (i)
>   Valid  domestic  driving  licence  (genuine  and  copy) (ii)     Valid
>   passport  (genuine  and  copy) (If  applicant  has  been  in the 
>   other  country,  passport  copy  can  be  allowed) (iii)    (3)
>   passport  size photos (iv)    FEC (20) or US $ (20)
>
> (m)    Required  documents  to  exchange  Myanmar  driving  licence 
>   from  Foreign driving  licence (i)      His / Her Driving  Licence 
>   (genuine  and  copy) (ii)     Passport (genuine  and  copy) (iii) (3) photos (iv)    Application  form  of  concerned  company (v) 60 FEC  and  (1200ks)  for  Right  Hand  drive  countries (iv)    70
>   FEC  and  (1200ks)  for  Left-Hand  drive  countries

They are not a party to the 1949 Geneva Convention though AAA notes on the IDPs which it issues that Myanmar "honors" such permits. [There is evidence](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/ViewDetailsIII.aspx?src=IND&mtdsg_no=XI-B-19&chapter=11&Temp=mtdsg3&clang=_en#EndDec) that they accepted the 1968 Vienna convention. In principle, it seems one can pass the licensing hurdle.

However, you may be required to borrow a car from a friend, buy one, or rent in another country and drive in. [The 1989 Motor Vehicle Law](http://www.myanmarrtad.com/?q=en/article/118) Rule 113 says (in the English version):

> Unless a "D" driving licence or a "E" driving licence prescribed under
>   rule 98, Chapter IV of these rules is held no person shall be entitled
>   to drive a hired vehicle concerned.

I should point out that rule 98 of those rules in in Ch. V and says nothing about licenses, and the relevant rule seems to be rule 58 (5=၅, 9=၉). Correspondingly, car rental companies all seem to rent car and driver, not just car.